# How to force canvas drawn views to be in an exact dimension?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-viewgroup

I'm trying to **force a drawn view to be in an exact dimension.** 
No matter how I try **it ignores the dimensions.**

Code:

My view to be **drawn in 250x250 pixels:**

```
public class MyCustomView extends View {
    public MyCustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout(getContext());

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
            textView.setText("[text#" + i + "]");
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            layout.addView(textView);
        }

        int dimension = 250;

        layout.measure(
                dimension,
                dimension);

        layout.layout(0, 0,
                dimension,
                dimension);

        layout.draw(canvas);

    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**The layout clearly not renders in 250x250 pixels.**

If I swap the FlowLayout to a standard Android SDK layout, like to a Linear Layout, the result is the same.

Please help if you can.

Comment: If there are so many child then how can the view will have 250x250

Comment: @Majoj It is the point of the whole conception, I would like to crop the invisible children. The viewgroup has to be constant diemnsion, the children "doesnt matter".